# Jaccard similarity in python

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, similarity

I am trying to find the jaccard similarity between two documents. However, i am having hard time to understand how the function `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score()` works behind the scene.As per my understanding the Jaccard's sim =  intersection of the terms in docs/ union of the terms in docs.

Consider below example:
My DTM for the two documents is:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

above func. give me the jaccard sim score

```
print(sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score(tf_matrix[0,:],tf_matrix[1,:]))
0.25
```

I am trying to find the score on my own as :

```
intersection of terms in both the docs = 4
total terms in doc 1 = 6
total terms in doc 2 = 6
Jaccard = 4/(6+6-4)= .5
```

Can someone please help me understand if there is something obvious i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#jaccard-similarity-score):

> In binary and multiclass classification, the Jaccard similarity coefficient score is equal to the classification accuracy.

Therefore in your example it is calculating the proportion of matching elements. That's why you're getting `0.25` as the result.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So, is it where the frequency matches(2nd and 3rd term)? If yes, would that be an effective way to get the similarity score for the documents?

Comment: Set Jaccard similarity can be a measure of similarity between documents, however metrics such as `TF-IDF` are more common in bag-of-word model of documents.

Comment: By the way check out `https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html`. There you may find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> According to me
>
> intersection of terms in both the docs = 2.
>
> peek to peek intersection according to their respective index. As we need to predict correct value for our model.
>
> Normal Intersection  = 4. Leaving the order of index.

```
# so,
jaccard_score = 2/(6+6-4) = 0.25
```